# Unable to choose the fields to be used in the formula field in salesforce

Tags: formula, formula-field

I am new to the salesforce and trying to create the `formula` field, I have the following condition which I want to create.

```
AND(DoNotCall, HasOptedOutOfEmail, HasOptedOutOfFax)
```

But I'm not finding `HasOptedOutOfEmail` and `HasOptedOutOfFax`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are highlighting the Account lookup field and on the right its highlighting all the fields of account.

Instead in the second column scroll down and you will find the fields you are looking for in the contact object.
[image]

I am assuming the fields you need as part of the 'AND' condition are already part of the contact object.

Answer (score 0):

The HasOptedOutOfEmail's label name is 'Email Opt Out', and the HasOptedOutOfFax's label name is 'Fax Opt Out'. 
Please verify.